# vlan for ip cameras and nvr

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, ip-camera

I had an existing tcp/ip network setup and I added 4 ip cameras and an nvr to it. The traffic load went up and I had some performance issues especially to the routers.
As a solution I thought to add VLAN for the cameras and the nvr. So I did add a VLAN in two of the ports (now these 2 ports are tagged) of an AC1000 Wi-Fi RouterE5350 and connected the 4 ip cameras and the nvr.

Now the VLAN is not accessible from the rest of network and I can't see the cameras and the nvr.
How do I go about having access to these devices from the outside of the VLAN?

It is true that i'm missing a lot things to this topic and I would appreciate any guidance and help. Thanks!

Comment: What are these two ports connected to – a switch? Is the same VLAN configured on the switch as well? What's the VLAN configuration looking like on your router?

Comment: @user1686
 I am not allowed to add pictures so I will try to explain in words. The two ports are connected to 2 switches. Switch 1 has 2 cameras on it, the other switch has 2 cameras and the nvr. The 2 switches are ofcource connected. The switches are simple hubs, kind of  "dummies". the linksys AC1000 Wi-Fi RouterE5350 does the vlan by "tagging" the port.

Comment: @user1686 just to clarify, switch1 goes to port1 on the router and switch2 goes to port2 on the router. Switch1 & 2 are not directly connected.

Comment: What do you mean by "the 2 switches are of course connected"? Connected to each other *and* to the router? That's not really good... Also ports aren't "tagged", specific VLANs on those ports are tagged – something on the other end needs to be able to untag them in order for the VLAN to work. If your switches don't support VLAN tagging, then your cameras need to – do they?

Comment: @user1686 I added a second clarification above to explain that `the 2 switches are of course connected` I don't mean to each other but through the wifi router. Could you please explain your second comment `specific VLANs on those ports are tagged..`. Could you please point some resource that explains deeper the issue?

Comment: I don't know of any good articles about this. The summary, though, is that "tagging" literally means "stamp each packet with its VLAN ID" (an extra header is inserted), which is only necessary when there are _multiple_ VLANs on the same port. When a port only has one VLAN, its packets usually remain untagged (because it's already clear which VLAN they belong to). When a port has multiple VLANs, one of them still remains untagged (the others are tagged). E.g. port1 could be in "VLAN 1 (untagged)", port2 be in "VLAN 4 (untag.) + 1 (tag.) + 6 (tag.)", and port3 "VLAN 6 (untag.)".

Comment: Since "tagged" packets are modified by inserting the tag, devices will no longer recognize them as normal packets – and more importantly, won't _send_ properly tagged packets back – unless specifically told to (for example) "use VLAN 2". If they don't specifically have VLAN support (IP cameras most likely don't) they'll only send/receive untagged packets, so the ports need to have just that one untagged VLAN on them (aka "access ports").

Comment: Back to the topic... On your router, did you configure a separate IP network for the VLAN? (Each VLAN would have its own subnet, with the router forwarding packets between them.) And could you clarify "The traffic load went up" – do you mean traffic between cameras and NVR, or something else? (Normally your switches should have handled it directly, without it even touching the router.)

Comment: @user1686 the two separate switches (each switch with two cams) are connected to two separate ports on wifi router. one of the switches has the nvr as well. I haven't setup a separate subnet. cams, nvr etc are all in the same subnet. I don't know if i can setup a separate subnet in each wifi router port. I have to look this up. By saying 'The traffic load went up' I mean that if all this setup in the same subnet and the cams broadcast all their traffic  to the whole network and not just the nvr.

Comment: You don't need a separate subnet per port, you need a separate subnet **per VLAN.** If the router supports VLANs officially, it should support configuring the subnet info for virtual VLAN interfaces as well.

Comment: @user1686 I can't add subnet in this VLAN with my AC1000 Wi-Fi RouterE5350. So I can't access this VLAN via routing or otherwise from outside this VLAN. If this is true I need a second router to form a new subnet and allow access to it via routing.